# How can I add searchable InventoryID (User Defined Field) in the Cases module of Acumatica?

Tags: customization, acumatica

How can I add a searchable inventoryID field in the cases module on Acumatica? I already added a custom field but can I make it searchable?
Is it possible to make this InventoryID User Defined Field searchable from the inventoryItem table? Screenshot Below:[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could put the [StockItem] attribute on the field if you want it to be a selector of all Stock Items. If you want to use a different query you could just use a regular PXSelector like

`[PXSelector(typeof(Search<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Where<...` etc.

Comment: Thank you Rochelle, how do I add the StockItem attribute on the field?

Comment: In the DAC, above your InventoryID field. Here is an example:


        #region InventoryID
        public abstract class inventoryID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<inventoryID> { }
        protected Int32? _InventoryID;
        [StockItem(Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
        [PXDefault]
        public virtual Int32? InventoryID
        {
            get
            {
                return this._InventoryID;
            }
            set
            {
                this._InventoryID = value;
            }
        }
        #endregion

Comment: Sorry about that, it doesn't really let me paste code in a comment. But the [StockItem] attribute goes above your custom field in the DAC. You can also look at INLocation.cs as another example.